# Opencart 2.0 image upload issue in admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart

I am getting a very weird issue in open cart admin panel. I am not getting where is the issue.

in admin->catalog->product page, when I am editing or adding any product, at that time, when I am choosing "image" tab for upload the image for that product, then after uploading the image or selecting the image from the image manager, my image is not coming in a thumbnail size, it is increase its size.

see the image for reference

**it should come like this.**

[image: it should come like this]

**but it is coming like like this**
[image]

This is not happening for all time, for some time it is happening.

after inspect this html. I got this code for extra images in table->tfoot

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="http://localhost/image/catalog/12.jpg"><img src="http://localhost/image/catalog/1-150R41519434c.jpg"></td>
        <td class="text-left">
            <button type="button" onclick="addImage();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-primary" data-original-title="Add Image"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

but in my code, admin->catalog->product.php
when I have open the controller, it is calling get_form() function. and it is loading product_form.tpl file.

and in this tpl file there is not such html code exist.
This is the actual code written in my form html

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="addImage();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_image_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

also in this page, for adding the image, a javascript code is calling. this is the code for adding the image

```
function addImage() {
    html  = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
    html += '  <td class="text-left"><a href="" id="thumb-image' + image_row + '"data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" /><input type="hidden" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="input-image' + image_row + '" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][sort_order]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#image-row' + image_row  + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#images tbody').append(html);

    image_row++;
}
```

As you guys can see, there is no such type of code which is adding the image in tfoot of this table.

I am very frustrate with this issue. 
can you help me please.

Comment: If this happen, check your console error, see all content loaded successfully? or not. sound like a `css` or `js` not loaded at that time.

Comment: @pedram : hi, I have checked, I found this. In my console, that image is getting 304 instead of 200

Comment: @pedram : Also I have checked, all css and js is loading in both case.

Comment: Hmm.. i don't think `304` be cause of this. I can't say something technical to solve this because need to see live version, but if you want to get ride of this you can set a certain `width` and `height` like `width="100"` and height `height="100"` on html part, it solve your problem in a tricky way.

Comment: @pedram : I have already put height and width in code, but also this is not working. This is happens only for some time, like in incognito mode, or open for the very first time. and also, the extra big image not comes in the same div everytime. it is comming in different div each time

Comment: Sounds similar to me, do you using any `cdn` like using jquery or bootstrap with `cdn`?

Comment: No @pedram, I am not using any CDN, all the css and js of bootstrap/jquery is in my directory.

Comment: So there is no guess..

Comment: What is your oc version? 2.0.0.0 ?
Are you using any related vqmod or ocmod script?

Comment: @DigitCart, yes for both question